# Is there a differentiable approximation of argmax() function

Tags: pytorch, torch, argmax

Output a vector corresponding to which the position of the maximum value in the input vector approaches 1 and the other positions approach 0. This function needs to be differentiable.

For example:

```
import torch
a = torch.Tensor([2,3,4,5,4,3,2], require_grad=True)
b = f(a)
>>> b
tensor([1e-10, 1e-10, 1e-10, 0.9999999, 1e-10, 1e-10, 1e-10], grad_fn=<...>)
```

Is there a practical way?

Comment: look into softmax

Comment: @jkr softmax not good enough

Comment: What does "not good enough" mean? Not enough smooth or too much smooth?

Comment: There's a similar discussion; if you want to refer, here's the link: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/differentiable-argmax/33020.